# Installing an Office 365 Add-in (E1 license vs E3)

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm developing an add-in for Office 365 (Outlook 2016 to be specific). I've found that I cannot install the Add-in into Outlook unless I have an **E3** license subscription to Office 365. If a user is using an **E1** license, the section to add a custom Add-in is simply not there.

Being in an organisation, it was necessary to contact IT support in order to get an E3 license. However, I am curious to know if the above is really the case. Perhaps there is some parameter or subtle change which is configured when a user is upgraded to E3? Maybe it's possible to activate the Add-in via some workaround? I only ask because one must also fully reinstall Office 365 upon receiving the license and no doubt it is probably frustrating for IT to be hassled with constant requests.

note: for reasons out of my control the Microsoft Add-in centralised deployment process is not feasible.

Comment: If you did find a way to circumvent the requirement, it would most likely violate the license agreement, which is not going to make your organization's IT or legal department very happy.

Comment: I suppose I wasn't really clear with that point. To rephrase, I am not entirely sure if the E3 license is **required**, only I know the add-in **works** if you have it. If there is an option which enables the add-in (perhaps an Outlook checkbox somewhere in the settings, for example) that would be much preferred.